# TableView cell height depending on text not working for two labels only one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I am having an issue with getting my custom cell to obtain the correct height when the label is applied to it. I can get it to work on one label but not two labels, no matter what I try either only one label or the other obtains the correct height. The label is meant to change lines automatically depending on how much text there is then using the pin feature to add constraints it automatically sizes depending on the text. I will post some of the code below to get an idea, along with screenshots of the view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.tableViewObject.estimatedRowHeight = 280.0;
 self.tableViewObject.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; 
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableViewObject addSubview:refreshControl];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ReviewCell1Test";



    ReviewCell1TableViewCell *cell = (ReviewCell1TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReviewCell1Test" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    cell.reviewtext.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ -%@",[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"desc"],[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"]];
    cell.tutortext.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ -%@",[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"desc"],[Tutortrackinbud[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"]];
    return cell;
}
```

[image: This is what happens when the view loads]
[image: This is the view]

Comment: Are you sure all of your constraints are correct? You shouldn't be seeing so much red.

Comment: The red is because I am not going by the suggested ones by xCode but even if I select all the suggested ones (which should work) i'm having the same issue.

Comment: @random if I reset and go by the suggested ones the top text label resizes correctly but the bottom one does not.

Comment: That's interesting. your code looks correct, all I can assume is that the constraints are causing the problem. I just tested on a sample project in which all constraints were properly set and it works fine.

Comment: you could try adding this: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}`

Comment: @random just tried adding that, didn't change anything. I have reset all the constraints in the view to the suggested ones and it's still happening. From what I can see there is blue lines everywhere on the view and it looks like the constraints are where they should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110393/discussion-between-random-and-curtis-boylan).